# userID in gae localhost debugging

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth

i am currently testing the OAuth feature on `GAE Java`. I test it locally to avoid the long deploying time. However, my `userID` differs between authentification via `OAuth` and via the `UserService`.

Here is how I do it with the `UserService`

```
  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

  if (user != null) {
      log.info("Identified User via google UserService: " + user.getNickname() + "[" + user.getUserId( ) + "]");
  }
```

And that is how I do it with `OAuth`

```
    User user = null;
    try {
        OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
        user = oauth.getCurrentUser();
        
        log.info("User identified via OAuth: " + user.getNickname() + "[" + user.getUserId( ) + "]");
        
    } catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
        resp.getWriter().println(e.toString());
    }
```

Here is the output of the logging:

> INFO: Identified User via google UserService: example@example.com[13570591531824211424]
>
> INFO: User identified via OAuth: example@example.com[0]

You see the `userID` is different. How do I get the same `userID` both, `OAuth` and the `UserService`?